# How to join many tables side by side?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, concatenation

I have function for table $t$

```
t[n_] := Table[i*n, {i, 1, 3}];
```

For example t[1]=(1, 2, 3), t[2]=(2, 4, 6), and t[3]=(3, 6, 9)

To join $n=3$ tables side by side into $3\times3$ matrix I use

```
tall = Join[{t[1], t[2], t[3]}];
```

How to generalize coding for to work for $n=10, 100$ or $1000$ tables? With big number $m$ gives $m \times 3$ matrix.

Comment: `t /@ Range[100]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This

```
t[1]={1, 2, 3}; t[2]={2, 4, 6}; t[3]={3, 6, 9};t[4]={4,8,12};
tall=Table[t[i],{i,4}]
```

instantly gives you

```
{{1,2,3},{2,4,6},{3,6,9},{4,8,12}}
```

Replace the 4 with 10 or 100 or 1000

Answer (score 4):

To get `m` tables, you can [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) the function `t` on `Range[m]`:

```
m = 7;
t /@ Range[m]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12}, {5, 10, 15}, {6, 12, 
>         18}, {7, 14, 21}}

Alternatively, you can use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[t, m]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12}, {5, 10, 15}, {6, 12, 
>         18}, {7, 14, 21}}

Answer (score 3):

Add a DownValue to `t` such that it can also take a start `n` and an end `m` integer

```
t[n_] := Table[i*n, {i, 1, 3}];
t[n_, m_:0] := Table[i*(n+j), {j, 0, m-n}, {i, 1, 3}]
```

E.g.

```
t[5]
```

> {5,10,15}

```
t[3,5]
```

> {{3, 6, 9}, {4, 8, 12}, {5, 10, 15}}